# Rearrange Html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four div elements

```
    <div id="one" class="present" style="display: none;">1</div>
    <div id="two" class="present" style="display: none;">2</div>
    <div id="three" class="present" style="display: none;">3</div>
    <div id="four" class="present" style="display: none;">4</div>
```

At some point if it becomes

```
    <div id="one" class="present" style="display: none;">1</div>
    <div id="two" class="present" style="display: none;"></div>//this value gets deleted
    <div id="three" class="present" style="display: none;">3</div>
    <div id="four" class="present" style="display: none;">4</div>
```

I want it to get rearrange as

```
    <div id="one" class="present" style="display: none;">1</div>
    <div id="two" class="present" style="display: none;">3</div>//this moves up
    <div id="three" class="present" style="display: none;">4</div>//this moves up
    <div id="four" class="present" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Only these four elements have class "present" so I would think I could do something by iterating through it, but not sure how to get the result i am looking for

I tried:

```
    $(".present").each(function(){

    if ($(this).is(":empty"))
    {
        var target =  $(this);
        $(".present").each(function(){
             $(this).not(":empty");
             target.html($(this).html());
        });
    }
});
```

but this seem to put last div's html on the blank space, which is not what i want. I want them to push up.

ps: its not just one value that might get deleted. Any value in middle can get deleted. Even multiple values can get deleted, meaning, I could only have value in the last div, which i would ideally want to move to first div

Comment: posted what i tried and got hung on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a few issues in my last code.

I'm assuming from your original question that you don't want your div elements to be re-arranged but only your html content of each div.

Assuming you have this:

```
<div id="one" class="present">1</div>
<div id="two" class="present"></div>
<div id="three" class="present">3</div>
<div id="four" class="present"></div>
<div id="five" class="present">5</div>
<div id="six" class="present"></div>
<div id="seven" class="present"></div>
<div id="eight" class="present">8</div>
<div id="nine" class="present"></div>
<div id="ten" class="present"></div>
```

There probably is a shorter way but this seems to work.

```
$(".present").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is(":empty")) {
        var $nextItem = $this.nextAll().not(':empty').first();

        console.log($nextItem.html());

        if($nextItem.length){
            $this.html($nextItem.html());
            $nextItem.empty();
        }
    }
});
```

The resulting HTML is:

```
<div id="one" class="present">1</div>
<div id="two" class="present">3</div>
<div id="three" class="present">5</div>
<div id="four" class="present">8</div>
<div id="five" class="present"></div>
<div id="six" class="present"></div>
<div id="seven" class="present"></div>
<div id="eight" class="present"></div>
<div id="nine" class="present"></div>
<div id="ten" class="present"></div>
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvGHw/) - Use next non-empty value

---

As you can see in the resulting HTML, the div elements have not been re-ordered, just the HTML content has been shifted up, filling the blanks, thus leaving the blanks at the bottom. It works with multiple empty values missing in-between and at the end as well.

Comment: This is awesome!  great solution and way to help folks learn how to use next() with html() in moving around values, and still keeping the attribute sorting order the same.

Comment: @blachawk: I found a logical issue with `next()` as it only gets the immediate next element. I added `nextAll()` instead only taking the `.first()` of the result set I'm interested in. There probably is a more efficient way to do this. As OP seemed to have wanted to keep the element order and only shift the html values I couldn't think of a quick way to do this though.

Comment: you are right on track.  Not too many folks take advantage of nextAll().  I'm beginning to use it more myself too..Nice job.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this will do the trick:

```
$(".present").each(function(){
  if ($(this).is(":empty")){
    $(this).append($(this).parent());
  }
});
```

The append function removes the element and appends it to the target. By appending it to the container it's already in, it should be removed from the dom and reinserted at the end which should allow the lower objects to naturally move up.

If you wanted to animate the effect, you could clone the object rather than append, then target the first instance of it, animate the height value to 0 and then remove it.

---

So, in order to maintain the proper IDs on the containers, you could replace the markup of each with the markup of the next object, but there's quite a bit of content juggling involved there. I would suggest something like this instead (you would need to alter your id naming scheme slightly, to make it a little easier to set up. Not sure if that's an option for your situation.)

```
var myObjects = $(".present");
$(myObjects).each(function(){
  if ($(this).is(":empty")){
    $(this).append($(this).parent());
  }
}).each(function(){
  $(this).attr('id', 'a' + ($(this).index() + 1) )
});
```

So your ids would be a1, a2, a3, etc... the letter is because you cannot start an id or a class with a number, but could be replaced with something more descriptive if needed.

Depending on how you're using those IDs, you could possible just get rid of them altogether and check the index() of the object directly in whatever functions are making use of the IDs.

So if you're doing something like this:

```
$("#one").stuff();
```

.. you could instead use:

```
$(".present:eq(0)").stuff();
```

Of course that probably wouldn't work as well if you're referencing specific IDs in the css.

Comment: Don't you want to set the current html() value as the next() value? and prepend() empty value in the last .present element?

Comment: I missed that part of the question, that implied he wanted to maintain the order of id values, while shifting the html contents up. But rather than moving all the internal html, I would start a second iteration through the divs and reset the ids. Updating my answer now.

Comment: Nice effort in trying to give the OP what he wanted.

Comment: @relic180: +1 very nice. In addition, clone might be better in the first place if there are events bound to the individual elements that need to be preserved. If events are not bound to the elements using `on` with delegation or similar the events would be unbound after the append otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply do this:

```
$(".present:empty").each(function(index,item) {
    $(this).remove();
    $("#parent").append(this);
});
```

Just pull them out and add them back at the end of the list.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjwnv/) to illustrate.

Comment: @user1 happy that worked out for you, but the sorting order of the element attributes in Matt's fiddle solution is different from what you desired to have in your posted above.  You desired class names "one" "two" "three" "four" - Matt's order is different.

Comment: @user1: The resulting HTML is not in the expected order it seems. the resulting HTML re-ordered the complete Div elements. i.e: `id="one", id="three", etc..`. Your original post expected the divs to stay in the same order as before : `id="one", id="two", etc..` and only the values to move.

Comment: @user1 I posted in my answer a couple options to help maintain the ID order of the elements while reorganizing the html content...

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution... (*or maybe alternative*)
[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/HVR9M/1/)

```
function check(id) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(id),
        parent = ele.parentNode,
        len = parent.children.length,
        child = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        child = parent.children[i];
        if (child.nodeType === 1 && child.innerHTML.length === 0) {
            parent.appendChild(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert all empty ones after the last non empty one

```
$('.present:empty').insertAfter('.present:not(:empty):last');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4QYjW/

EDIT:

I didn't notice that you are only moving the text - You can do it like this

```
var withText = $('.present:not(:empty)').clone();// get all with text
$('.present').text(''); // clear all the text
// loop through and add the number text
$.each(withText, function(i,v){
    $('.present').eq(i).text($(v).text()); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k42Ny/